# Incorrect library reference in Maven, .m2\repository is coming twice

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

The Maven library reference in Eclipse is coming as

> C:Users\USERNAME\.m2\repository\.m2\repository\commons-collections\commons-collections\3.2.1\commons-collections-3.2.1.jar

**.m2\repository** is getting appended two times.

As shown in the below image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that in settings.xml the local repository was mentioned like

```
$user.home\.m2\repository
```

so it was creating the default .m2 repository and copying all the jars diretly into C: folder.

After that when I changed the local repository to

```
<localRepository>C:\Users\THOMNIG\.m2\repository</localRepository>
```

it was appending the extra .m2/repository to the M2_REPO variable and it was not able to find it

atlast when I changed the local repository in settings.xml to

**`<localRepository>C:/Users/THOMNIG/.m2/repository</localRepository>`**

Then the M2_REPO was getting referred correctly after doing a `mvn eclipse:eclipse`

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to specify `/.m2/repository` if `M2_REPO` already contains it.

Comment: The project is setup in this way only and is working in other machines. It is causing an issue only in my workspace.

Comment: Then your personal M2_REPO may be wrong. Put in M2_REPO on it's own and tell me it's content.
If it has /.m2 already in it then you need to remove it from M2_REPO or modify that line.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to run Maven Update with Force to Update Snapshots to fix it.